# How to null check when we test the false value?

Tags: javascript

I am getting consoled both `null` and `false` became `true` value. but i need only check against `false` and `true` alone from the `Boolean`. how to achieve that?

here is my code :

```
var x = {name:null} //gives true. but i am looking to avoid null
var y = {name:false}
var z = {name:true}

console.log(!x.name);
console.log(!y.name);
console.log(!z.name);
```

Comment: What output _would_ you expect for `null`?

Comment: Use the strict comparison operator. `if (x === false)...`

Comment: why there is a down vote? the forum is here to clear the doubts and fix the issues right?

Comment: @Ivar - object value has `null` as default. server provides `false` or `true` by condition. still the default value has `null` the UI consider as false, But I am trying to avoid that. only need to check against `true` or `false` instead of `null`

Comment: @user2024080 So you want `!null` to return `false`? In other words you only want `!false` to be true, and anything else should be `false`? Sounds like a job for `z.name === false`.

Comment: @Ivar - yes, you are correct. but there is some of instance other peoples are used ternary operators. just looking to update them instead write new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, unless you explicitly check for `null`. `null`, just like `undefined`, `0`, `''`, etc. is a falsy value, meaning any time you use the Boolean negation `!` it will return `true`.
The best you could do is add some code to make sure the value does not equal null.

```
const x = {name:null};
const y = {name:false};
const z = {name:true};

console.log(!x.name && x.name !== null); // false
console.log(!y.name && y.name !== null); // true
console.log(!z.name && z.name !== null); // false
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You could check the type and if necessary the value.

```js
var x = { name: null },
    y = { name: false },
    z = { name: true };

console.log(typeof x.name === 'boolean');
console.log(typeof y.name === 'boolean');
console.log(typeof z.name === 'boolean');
```